# How to a clickable list where the elements are rotated 45 degrees

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm looking to make a front page with a set of clickable areas which are rectangles rotated 45degrees. Imagine a set of books which have partially fallen over (by 45 degrees) and that their spines are each links to whatever is written on the back of the book.

So far I have.

```css
.somediv{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
}

ul{
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}

li{
    transform: rotate(315deg);
    display: block;
    width: 10vw;
}

a{
    display:inline-block;
    height:14.14vw;
    width: 145vh;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="somediv">
<ul>
  <li><a href="">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
</ul>
<div>
```

So far this is pretty good. But the links are very small. I thought I might just be able to expand their height and width and that would solve thing (it doesn't, I think because they are inline). At that point I tried to use display:box, but then if they are not perfectly size they make the window larger and that causes more problems than it solves. Thank you for your time.

Comment: `display:box,` is invalid.

Comment: you guess is right, they are inline element so change them to inline-block and you are good to go

Comment: Is there a way to make the a so that the text is in the centre of it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on here but your best option is to use [**`writing=mode`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) to make the text run top to bottom and then rotate as you desire.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.somediv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin:1em auto
}

ul {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

li {
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform: rotate(15deg); /* or your chosen angle */
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: red;
  margin:0;
}

a {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform:rotate(180deg); /* as right to left isn't supported yet */
}
```

```html
<div class="somediv">
<ul>
  <li><a href="">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
</ul>
<div>
```